# How to set DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in mysql with sqlalchemy?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am creating table with sqlalchemy.

```
user = Table('users', Metadata,
Column('datecreated', TIMESTAMP,                                  
            server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')),            
Column('datemodified', TIMESTAMP,                                 
               server_onupdate=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')),
)
```

But this will not set `DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

I checked out [How do you get SQLAlchemy to override MySQL "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2450593) but that will for literal I need to wire that in create table definition.

Comment: For those who like myself might end up here looking for the same functionality on Postgres: the solution is very different, and is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70946151/how-to-set-default-on-update-current-timestamp-in-postgres-with-sqlalchemy/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're on MySQL 5.6 or later please scroll down for the relevant answer. Users of older versions, please read this one.

---

Until MySQL 5.6. in one table, you can only have one 'automated' TIMESTAMP column.

From: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html

> For one TIMESTAMP column in a table, you can assign the current
>   timestamp as the default value and the auto-update value. It is
>   possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for
>   initializing the column, for the auto-update value, or both. It is not
>   possible to have the current timestamp be the default value for one
>   column and the auto-update value for another column.

Comment: if i will write 
`user = Table('users', Metadata,
Column('datecreated', DateTime),
Column('datemodified', TIMESTAMP,                                 
               server_onupdate=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')),
)` 
Then it will work for DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: I checked with this example but it's not set the DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. when we use for single column. :(

Comment: If this is not possible then also please let me know how can i set onupdate trigger in sqlalchemy?

Comment: For those who come after on mysql 5.6, dont stop here, there's a good answer down below...

Comment: @domoarrigato: I've added this at the top of my answer.

Answer (score 28):

You can hijack the server_default to set also the ON UPDATE:

```
Column('datemodified', TIMESTAMP,
       server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```

This generates the following column entry:

```
datemodified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

However, Mchl's answer still applies: There can be only one automated TIMESTAMP column in a table (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html)

Also note that the order of the columns is of importance!  If you have a TIMESTAMP column without DEFAULT and ON UPDATE modifiers, and it is the first TIMESTAMP column in your table,
it automatically will be set to DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html)

So this is fine:

```
Column('datemodified', TIMESTAMP,
       server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
Column('datecreated', TIMESTAMP)
```

while this is not:

```
Column('datecreated', TIMESTAMP)
Column('datemodified', TIMESTAMP,
       server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```

In order to set the `datecreated' to the current time during first entry of a row, just set its value explicitly to NULL. Again, from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp.html:

> By default, TIMESTAMP columns are NOT NULL, cannot contain NULL
>   values, and assigning NULL assigns the current timestamp.

Comment: This was the only way that worked for me, no combination of `server_onupdate=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')` would do the trick.  if you are on mysql 5.6+ (which, by now, most people should be), this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 9):

This worked on Mysql 8

```
sa.Column('created_at', sa.TIMESTAMP, server_default=func.now()),
sa.Column('updated_at', sa.TIMESTAMP, server_default=text('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'))
```

For some reason the server_onupdate options was not working.

Answer (score 6):

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

Column('datemodified',
       TIMESTAMP,                                 
       server_onupdate=text(
           ' ON UPDATE '.join([str(func.current_timestamp())] * 2)))
```

This way you use SQLAlchemy's inner `func.current_timestamp()` function.

Answer (score 1):

In the model I just use ( without `()` for `utcnow` ):

```
from datetime import datetime

last_modified = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.utcnow)
```

Everytime I update the row in one of the columns - it will update `last_modified` automatically.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want is DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MySQL, then just setting the TIMESTAMP column in sqlalchemy to be non-nullable works

```
Column(TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
```

Comment: no this doesn't work