# How to automatically update ORM object attributes with client-side values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-api-gateway

I'm using aws api gateway to create my rest api and I'm using lambda layers to define my sqlalchemy models. I'm using Mysql as my RDBMS
I have a model defined as:

```
class Project(Base):
    __tablename__ = "project"
    name = Column(String(256))
    created_by = Column(String(256))
    updated_by = Column(String(256))
```

I have a function that get the user credentials who invoked the call based on jwt token and which return the username:

```
def get_user_creds(token):
    return jwt.decode(token, algorithms=["RS256"], options={"verify_signature": False})
```

I want to automatically fill the fields create_by and updated_by using the **get_user_creds** function.
Any solution to fill these columns on all transaction without explicitly setting them in model methods so that when I run

```
project = Project(name="project1")
session.add(project)
session.commit()
```

The transaction adds automatically created_by fields

Comment: It depends on the specific RDBMS. Which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mysql

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14498849/5320906) answer your question (check all the answers)?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I know that there are default and on_update properties for sqlalchemy Column. My issue is  that get_user_creds takes token as parameter which depends on each call. So how can I pass an argument to on_update properties.
(updated_by = Column(String(256), on_updated=get_user_creds(token))

Answer (score 0):

You could use a before_flush event to update the values

```py
def get_user():
    """ dummy function for demonstration purposes """
    return f"user_{datetime.datetime.now().second % 10}"

@event.listens_for(Session, 'before_flush')
def receive_before_flush(session, flush_context, instances):
    current_user = get_user()
    for obj in session.new:
        if isinstance(obj, Project):
            obj.created_by = current_user
    for obj in session.dirty:
        if isinstance(obj, Project):
            obj.updated_by = current_user


with Session(engine) as sess:
    p_1 = Project(id=1, name="project_1_original")
    sess.add(p_1)
    sess.commit()
    print(p_1)
    # Project(id=1, name='project_1_original', created_by='user_4', updated_by=None)
    sleep(2)
    p_1.name = "project_1_updated"
    sess.commit()
    print(p_1)
    # Project(id=1, name='project_1_updated', created_by='user_4', updated_by='user_6')
```

Comment: my problème is that get_user function takes the user token.